# Apply pointer-events: none to mini reputation graph label

Tags: feature-request, design, reputation-graph

Currently, when hovering over the rep graph on the Activity tab, the label obstructs the mouse pointer, preventing me from hovering over sections off to the right without moving the mouse out of the graph then back in again at the desired point. Adding `pointer-events: none` (which has good [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), by the way) would eliminate this issue completely. *(In the GIF below the line was added by me beforehand, it's not there by default)*

> [image]

I'm *well aware* that this can be done with a custom stylesheet, but I believe adding this extra line of CSS should be trivial for a label that works this way.

Comment: This might be a better place to file a bug report (If they're still using highcharts): https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Are they?

Comment: Still? Most likely: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=highcharts

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215483/184030), this one's likely a custom chart, independent from highcharts.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. I guess you're right.